# Auto suggestion of package doesn't happen after upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04.

After the upgrade, I noticed a difference. Previously, if I type a command that's not available on the system, it'd automatically recommend the package name (assuming the command is in fact exists in some repos). For example:

```
$ htop
  Command 'htop' not found, but can be installed with:

  sudo apt install htop
```

But now, I just get:

```
$ htop
htop: command not found
```

i.e. the suggestion with apt install is missing now.

Any idea what might have caused this change in behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it's because of a missing package (I must have accidentally removed it during the upgrade to Focal or it was "autoremove"d unintentionally). The way to get it the auto-suggestion was to install the package `command-not-found`:

```
$ sudo apt search command-not-found
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
command-not-found/focal-updates,now 20.04.4 all [residual-config]
  Suggest installation of packages in interactive bash sessions

packagekit-command-not-found/focal 1.1.13-2ubuntu1 amd64
  Offer to install missing programs automatically

python3-commandnotfound/focal-updates,now 20.04.4 all [installed,auto-removable]
  Python 3 bindings for command-not-found.
```

Example before & after:

```
$ smartctl
smartctl: command not found
$ sudo apt install command-not-found -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  command-not-found
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 5240 B of archives.
After this operation, 35.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 command-not-found all 20.04.4 [5240 B]
Fetched 5240 B in 0s (18.5 kB/s)           
Selecting previously unselected package command-not-found.
(Reading database ... 43980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../command-not-found_20.04.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking command-not-found (20.04.4) ...
Setting up command-not-found (20.04.4) ...
$ smartctl 

Command 'smartctl' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install smartmontools

$
```